# Sampling distribution of the skewness / kurtosis from non normal distributions?

Tags: distributions, sampling, skewness, kurtosis

Is there some sort of approximation or analytic definition of the sampling distributions of the skewness and kurtosis when samples are taken from a NON-normal distribution?

I have been looking for some article or book chapter that may talk about them but the best I can come up is people claiming it is "difficult" to derive.

I did find this article that is *somewhat* relevant:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2988433?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

but it only looks at the special case of the chi-square distribution.

Comment: Every possible distribution you want to know about would have to be done separately. Most of these won't be tractable (though some simple cases will be). Under certain conditions the distributions (via the fact that the numerators are averages and applying Slutsky's theorem to the ratio) will converge to normal distributions as $n\to\infty$ but the convergence (when it happens at all) may be extremely slow - in many cases much too slow to be of any use. You can of course explore the sampling distribution via simulation. What do you need the sampling distribution for?

Comment: Do you need a specific measure of skewness and/or kurtosis? Or is this simply to test whether the distribution is statistically different from a theoretical distribution?

Comment: Thank you both for your insights. I am exploring various data-generating algorithms for simulation purposes that allow the user to specify univariate skewness or kurtosis. I have reason to believe some algorithms work better than others so I assumed comparing the data generated by these algorithms with some theoretical results would be useful.

Comment: Here:  http://clinchem.aaccjnls.org/content/35/2/330.long is a peper investigating sampling distribution for skewness. Even for the normal distribution they use simulation.  Maybe that is the best one can do.

Comment: @Jon: Maybe to use to test general symmetry of the distribution